# Add filter to gmail account via HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm developing a chrome extension for gmail and I'm aware of the Admin SDK API

[Admin SDK: managing filters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_a_filter)

From everything I've read, I can't use this API with a standard @gmail.com address.

doing a POST to

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/gmail.com/2.0/me/filter

just results in a bad URL. I've allowed access to the admin SDK in the Developer's Console.

I have no problem using the other GMail API, my Oauth2 flow seems to work fine.

Has anyone had any luck programmatically creating a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, your findings are correct: it's not possible to do this currently for @gmail.com accounts (Gmail API exposes nothing about filters, Admin SDK is only for Google Apps domains).

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why google chooses not to expose filters in the Gmail API. It's so spiffy in general.

Comment: The Gmail API is very new, there's still time yet to add auxiliary features like filters.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving, I encountered this in my research for [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607996/how-to-automatically-set-gmail-filter-via-chrome-extension)

Basically, even though Gmail Settings API won't let you and I found lack of documentation disturbing, there is a way to programmatically set a filter *for logged in user*. It requires simply issuing a POST request in gmail's page environment (script injection, likely browser extension). In answer linked above you'll find a working example; all paying credit to [this small API project](https://github.com/GrexIt/Gmail-Filters-Js-api) which greatly helped to set this up.